# How to output Python3 (unicode) strings while ignoring un-encodable characters

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

Consider the following terminal command line

```
python3 -c 'print("hören")'
```

In most terminals this prints "hören" (German for "to hear"), in *some* terminals you get the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' 
in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In my Python3 program I don't want that just printing out something *can* raise an exception like this, instead I'd rather like to output the characters which will not raise an exception.

So my questions is: **How can I output in Python3 (unicode) strings while ignoring un-encodable characters?**

---

#### Some notes

**What I've tried so far**

1. I tried using `sys.stdout.write` instead of`print`, but the encoding problem still can occur.
2. I tried encoding the string in byes via

   ```
   bytes=line.encode('utf-8')
   ```

   This never raises an exception on print, but even in capable terminals non-ascii characters are replaced by their code point numbers.
3. I tried using the `decode` method with the `'ignore'` parameter:

   ```
   bytes=line.encode('utf-8')
   decoded=bytes.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
   print(decoded)
   ```

   But the problem is not the decoding in the string but the enconding *in* the print function.

**Here some terminals which appear not to be capable of all characters**

- bash shell inside Emacs on macOS.
- Receiving a "printed" string in Applescript via `do shell script`, e.g.:

  ```
  set txt to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3 -c \"print('hören')\" "
  ```

*Update: These terminals all return from `locale.getpreferredencoding()`the value `US-ASCII`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way is to set [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) variable depending on the terminal you are using.

For UTF-8-enabled terminals you can do:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING='utf-8'
```

For printing '?'s in ASCII terminals, you can do:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING='ascii:replace'
```

Or even better, if you don't care about the encoding, you should be able to do:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=':replace'
```

Comment: Great answer! I have somewhat success with setting `export LANG=en_AU.UTF-8`, but that's quite bruce force; your method is much more targeted.